# Is there a way to customize a WebChat Bot that is embedded in a SharePoint modern site template?

Tags: javascript, azure, sharepoint, chatbot

I am trying to customize the default template of a WebChat bot without using the Bot Framework SDK. This bot will be embedded in a SharePoint modern site template.

It looks like there are ways to customize the WebChat bot through a `<style>` block or JavaScript, but I don't have access to my site's source code as I am using the SharePoint modern template, which does not support script embeds or Custom CSS. Inline CSS to customize the `<iframe>` itself also has limited capabilities.

As far as I know, I would have to use the Bot Framework SDK to create a custom chatbot that can be then embedded into the SharePoint site using an `<iframe>`. Is there an alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

We have posted a blog on August about how to embed a bot using web chat. Please refer to it:
https://blog.botframework.com/2020/08/05/embed-a-bot-in-a-website/

More information can be found in Botframework blog as well. Thanks.